# Increasing heap space automatically in project using wildfly (not in standalone.conf)

Tags: jvm, wildfly, heap-memory

I'd like to increase the heap space of the jvm using Wildfly. After using google, I figured I can change the standalone.conf, but that's not what I need.

I have a project with a standalone.xml, some properties and a service which executes the standalone.sh with a few command line arguments (I already tried passing an argument here).

After building the project I get a rpm, which I'm using to run docker and there I check if the heap space is increased. Our client doesn't want to change it manually in the standalone.conf. They want it to be configured within the project. I thought I could maybe add it somewhere in the standalone.xml, but I can't figure out at which position or how.

I've read that I can add a host.xml or domain.xml, but I don't think this is what I need. I don't really know anything about servers, but I don't think we have a server group.

I also tried to add a bin-folder with a new standalone.conf and replace the one in wildfly using the rpm-spec, but this didn't work as well. Another dummy file I created for testing got added, but not my standalone.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using standalone you've got to change the `standalone.conf` or edit the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable. It's too late by the time the `standalone.xml` would be parsed as it's a JVM setting.